# Bug in a generic filter function in Scala

Tags: scala

I am writing a filter function in Scala and although I feel good about what I am trying to do I can not figure out why it will not recognize my List or what this bug is telling me. I have tried editing the syntax but nothing seems to fix it

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Empty extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[A]( x : A, xs : List[A]) extends List[A]

def filter[A](f: A => Boolean, list: List[A]): List[A] =
for { 
    a <- list
    if (f(a)) 
} yield a

<console>:93: error: value filter is not a member of List[A]
   a <- list
```

[Check out code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtoFt.png)

Comment: `List` is a class type. You can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: So you want to implement filter using filter? You do not understand how **for** comprehensions are desugared.

Comment: I have changed the variable name and the same error occurs

Comment: @OJuicedUp; Post the code that generates the error. Don't post a link. Don't post an image. Post the code.

Comment: sure thing @jwvh

Comment: The posted code compiles and runs without error: `filter((x:Int) => x < 4, List(5,3,9,1))`

Comment: I still get the same errors, I have included the type definition for more clarity @jwvh

Answer (score 4):

So, if we first understand that **for comprehensions** are [*sugar syntax*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) for `map`, `flatMap` and `filter`. Then we can see that your attempt of defining filter is equivalent to:

```
list.filter(a => f(a))
```

Which obviously doesn't make sense.
You can not define `filter` in terms of `filter`...

Well, you actually can, that is what recursion is all about, and actually that is the correct way of solving the problem.
With the extra help of [**pattern matching**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html).

So a recursive function is the best way to process a recursive data structure like `List`.
The process is actually quite straight forward, we need to figure out what to do in the base case and what to do in the recursive case *(which probably will require a recursive call)*.
*(note: I changed the function signature, this new signature allows better syntax and better type inference)*

```
/** Returns a new list with only the elements that satisfied the predicate. **/
def filter[A](list: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): List[A] = list match {
  case Empty => ??? // Base case. Tip: tink in what is the filter of an empty list.
  case Cons(a, tail) => ??? // Recursive case. Tip: you probably will need to call the function recursively.
}
```

Once you fill the holes, you will have a proper filter function. But, we got a problem, since this is a recursive solution, trying to filter a very big list will result in a *StackOverflowError* which is not ideal, so what can we do?
[**Tail-Recursion**](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/tail-recursive-algorithms/#:%7E:text=A%20tail%2Drecursive%20function%20is,for%20each%20level%20of%20recursion!) to the rescue!

The idea is simple, we need to keep an accumulator for holding intermediate values.
*(note: it is usually a good idea to keep the tail function as an inner function)*

```
/** Returns a new list with only the elements that satisfied the predicate. **/
def filter[A](list: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): List[A] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[A], acc: ???): List[A] =
    remaining match {
      case Cons(a, as) => ??? // Recursive case.
      case Empty => ??? // Base case, we are done! Tip: Is the output correct?
    }

  loop(remaining = list, acc = ???)
}
```

Once you fill the holes, you will have a good `filter` function.

*(Final note: Following a technique called [**type tetris**](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2017/04/11/type-tetris.html) probably will help to get the correct solution)*

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have a suggestions for you -

1. Don't use semicolons in Scala.
2. Use `camelCase` for `variable` names in Scala. (You can use `CAPITAL_SNAKE_CASE` for constants though).
3. Use `CapitalCamelCase` for `trait`, `class` and `object` names.

Now, you are naming your paramter as `List` which conflicts with class `List`.

So, your code need to be changed to this,

```scala
def filter[A](f: A => Boolean, list: List[A]): List[A] =
  for {
    a <- list
    if (f(a))
  } yield a

// use the defined method to filter the list
filter[Int](i => i > 2, List(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice but even changing the parameter and the changes you suggested just gives me the same error, value filter is not a member of List[A]

Comment: Your problem is that you are using your own custom `List` and not the scala `List`. `for` comprehension in Scala is a syntactical sugar which at the very least require `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, `filter` and `withFilter` methods to work. And since your `List` class does not have these implemented, it will not work with `for`. Also you need to stop using console, try these out in a proper scala project instead of console.